# How to replace old external links with new ones in all Wordpress posts automatically?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

How to replace old external links with new ones in all Wordpress posts automatically?

The links are in [embed] codes in the posts.

```
http://old-232.external.link.com/folder/etc.mp4
```

with

```
http://newexternallink.com/~newfolder/folder/etc.mp4
```

Note: the new external link is just an IP address.
Note2: the external links are in some of the posts.

Comment: describe more about your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a backup of your database before trying, you may try a search and replace, for example by using a tool plugin like [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/)

I guess there are several other options, but this is one of the plugins which gives you a preview on what is going to change, before doing the actual replacement.

If you add more specific details on what your replacing, you may get more spesific answers as well.

Comment: If it is only the first part of the urls which should be changed, I think I would have tried something like the tool linked to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easy with a simple plugin. Use the WordPress filter *the_content*

```
function my_content_filter($content){
  //only add text before WordPress posts
  if(is_single() && is_main_query()){
    //reply all occurances of the old URL with the new URL 
    $content = str_replace([OLD_LINK], [NEW_LINK],$content);
  } 
  return $content; 
} 

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_content_filter' );
```

For more on this check out my post on how to [Add Text Before And After Content In WordPress](http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/wordpress/add-text-before-after-content/) . Part 5 is about replacing content in all your posts or pages.